# US boundaries from 1780 map

Tags: shapefile, data, united-states, administrative-boundaries

Where can I find a shapefile of the US boundaries from the 1780s, including the original thirteen state boundaries?

Comment: Might be worth asking on opendata.stackexchange as well...

Answer (score 4):

There is an [atlas of historical boundaries](http://publications.newberry.org/ahcbp/pages/United_States.html) which features the data you're looking for. You can find the data in different formats on the bottom of the linked page.